# How to get another folder in same Project in Azure Linux Function

Tags: azure, function, path, azure-functions, azure-linux

Below is my project Structure:

```
ProjectX
- www (folder)
- - index.html (target file that want to access)
- MyFunc.cs (Function)
- local.settings.json
```

After I deployed to Azure Linux Function, I could not find a way to find `index.html`.

I tried below paths already:

1. /home/site/wwwroot/
2. /home/site/wwwroot/MyFunc/
3. /home/site/
4. /home/site/wwwroot/bin/
5. /home/site/wwwroot/bin/runtimes

Below is my coding for checking file:

```
public static async Task Run([ServiceBusTrigger(ServiceBusContext.MyQueueName, Connection = "ServiceBus")] Message msg, ILogger log)
{
    // change to different paths
    var testDir1 = new DirectoryInfo($@"/home/site/wwwroot/");
    FindFileInfo(testDir1, log);
}

public static void FindFileInfo(DirectoryInfo dir, ILogger log)
{
    FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles();
    foreach (FileInfo file in files)
    {
        log.LogInformation("Check File, RootDir=" + dir.FullName + ", File: {0}", file.Name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can use `context.FunctionAppDirectory`:

```
public static async Task Run([ServiceBusTrigger(ServiceBusContext.MyQueueName, Connection =
"ServiceBus")] Message msg, ILogger log, ExecutionContext context)
{
    var path = Path.Combine(context.FunctionAppDirectory, "www", "index.html");
}
```